# How do I add Google +1 to Addthis Button?

Tags: 7

I am using the Addthis Module version 6.x-3.0-beta2, the problem is that google +1 doesn't appear as one of the services. Anyone knows how to fix this ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

There is a tutorial http://www.addthis.com/features/google-plus1-button

Anyway, +1 is not a sharing service, I'm not sure that Addthis will add this (like there is no Facebook Like button). You can use the Customize service that addthis.module supports to add code described [here](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/+1button/#plusonetag-parameters).

Comment: The tutotial explains how to add it to the toolbox, I need to add it to the button. And Google +1 is listed on the AddThis Service Directory http://www.addthis.com/services/list. Any other ideas ?

Comment: I think that the +1 is implemented with the code I gave above. The services list is just a marketing. Even at addthis.com, when you click on "More options" there is no +1.

Comment: So there is no way to add the google +1 button inside of addthis, right ? Just outside ..